# c++ 20: how to find that the template argument is a rvalue reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, rvalue

I want to pass a parameter to a function, do `for`, and if the argument is `rvalue`, then move objects instead of copying. How to do that?

```
template<class T> void func(T&& v){
    for (auto&& item : v) {
        if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T>) { // ALWAYS FALSE
            // move object
            auto tmp = std::move(item);
        }
        else {
            // copy object
            auto tmp = item;
        }
    }
}

int main() { 
    std::vector<std::string> a {"11", "22"};
    func(std::move(a));
    std::cout << a[0].size(); // print 2 !! (must 0)
    return 0;
}
```

UPD: `auto tmp = std::forward<decltype(item)>(item)` will always copy too.

Comment: -> `std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>`.

Comment: BTW, even with that, as you move item, not the container, size would be 2, but with moved-string.

Comment: `std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>` - seems it's worked, thanks (I checked that is not moving when not rvalue)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think, it is not, because we are not moving vector, only strings inside it

Comment: @user3324131 Yeah, I noticed it afterwards that vector itself is not moved to anything, sorry for the mixup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when calling with `std::vector<std::string>&&`

then you have

```
template<class T> void func(T&& v) // T = std::vector<std::string>
```

and `std::is_rvalue_reference_v<std::vector<std::string>>` is `false`.

You need `std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>`.

If you call func with some `Obj&`, `T` would be deduced as `Obj&`, and `T&&` would also be (with collapsing rule) `Obj&`.

Comment: "*You need `std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>`*". - alternatively, `std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(v)>`

Answer (score 3):

You should only move the elements if your `std::vector` is also movable.

Starting with C++23 you can use `std::forward_like` to do this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct copy_only{
    copy_only() = default;
    copy_only(copy_only const&) { std::cout << "  copy_only copy\n"; }
};

struct copy_move{
    copy_move() = default;
    copy_move(copy_move const&) { std::cout << "  copy_move copy\n"; }
    copy_move(copy_move&&) { std::cout << "  copy_move move\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
void func(T&& v){
    for (auto&& item: std::forward<T>(v)) {
        [[maybe_unused]] auto tmp = std::forward_like<T>(item);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "elements are only copyable:\n";
    std::vector<copy_only> a(1);
    func(a);
    func(std::move(a));

    std::cout << "elements are also movable:\n";
    std::vector<copy_move> b(1);
    func(b);
    func(std::move(b));
}
```

```
elements are only copyable:
  copy_only copy
  copy_only copy
elements are also movable:
  copy_move copy
  copy_move move
```

If you are stuck on an older standard, you can easily workaround it by implementing `std::forward_like` as:

```cpp
#ifndef __cpp_lib_forward_like
namespace std{

    template <typename T, typename U>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto&& forward_like(U&& x) noexcept {
        constexpr bool is_adding_const
            = std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>) {
            if constexpr (is_adding_const) {
                return std::as_const(x);
            } else {
                return static_cast<U&>(x);
            }
        } else {
            if constexpr (is_adding_const) {
                return std::move(std::as_const(x));
            } else {
                return std::move(x);
            }
        }
    }

}
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer! I need to use c++20, so for myself I created this define `#define FORWARD_BY(T, item) std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&> ? std::move(item) : item` but I think your solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

`std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T>` will "extract" the `T` no matter what is the real type of `v` is, that's why it is always `false`. It's always a `T` without the `&&.` That said, don't do what you are doing. Just always try to `std::move`. If it is not possible to move, `std::move` will automatically fallback to a copy. So basically you do not have to manually handle the case.

Comment: I think this is not fully correct. I tried to move element INSIDE the vector, not the vector itself. My testing is showed, that elements in `for` statement always can be moved regardless of vector `lvalue` or `rvalue`.

Comment: `auto tmp = std::forward<decltype(item)>(item);` - will always copy. `auto tmp = std::move(item);` - always move.

Comment: sorry if it was unclear. you are not moving the elements of the vector in your code. you are iterating over a moved vector, but you will not be able to move out the elements; auto&& is a universal reference and will bind to whatever, and will hide the issue. If you replace it with your actual type, std::string&&, you will notice that it does not compile. There is an STL algorithm also called std::move which takes two iterators and will move all the elements away.

Comment: Thanks for detailed descriptions. But I can't use actual type, because I need a generic version of this function.

Comment: That is the unfortunate situation we are in cause the commitee standardized auto&& as universal reference instead of &&& which was discussed at some point.